# How can I generate a random point (x, y) 10 steps apart from y0(a, b) in xy-plane?

Tags: python, random

I have generated a random  point named `y0=(a,b)` in xy-plane , How can I generate another random point `(x,y)` 10 steps apart from `y0`?

note: by 10 steps apart from the firt point I don't mean the Euclidean distance. I mean the number of steps on lattice between the two point (a,b) and (x,y) which is given by |x-a|+|y-b|=10

My attempt(sometimes gives wrong result).

```
import random
y0=(random.randint(0,50),random.randint(0,50))# here I generated the first point.
y=random.randint(0,50)

# I used the formula  |x-a|+|y-b|=10.
x=(10 -abs(y-y0[1]))+y0[0]  or x=-(10 -abs(y-y0[1]))+y0[0]

x0=(x,y)
```

Comment: Is this for CodinGame? :)

Comment: Assuming your  2D plane is 50 x 50, are you checking boundary conditions ?

Comment: What does it mean to be "a step apart" from a point? One unit in Euclidean distance?

Comment: I don't mean the Euclidean distance.  I mean the number of steps on lattice between the two point (a,b) and (x,y) which   is given by   |x-a|+|y-b|=10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code generate a random point xy-plane named y0 then generate another point x0 10 steps apart from y0 in taxi distance .

------- begining of the code--------
   import random
   y0=(random.randint(0,50),random.randint(0,50))

```
  while True:

      y=random.randint(0,50)

      x=(10 -abs(y-y0[1]))+y0[0] 
      if (abs(x-y0[0])+abs(y-y0[1]))==10:
         x0=(x,y)
         break
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that your new point (x, y) is on a cercle of radius 10 and center (x0, y0). The random component is the angle.

```
import math as m
# radius of the circle
r = 10
# create random angle and compute coordinates of the new point
theta = 2*m.pi*random.random()
x = x0 + r*m.cos(theta)
y = y0 + r*m.sin(theta)
# test if the point created is in the domain [[0,50], [0, 50]] (see comments of PM2Ring)
while not ( 0<=x<=50 and 0<=y<=50 ) :
    # update theta: add pi/2 until the new point is in the domain (see HumanCatfood's comment) 
    theta += 0.5*m.pi
    x = x0 + r*m.cos(theta)
    y = y0 + r*m.sin(theta)
```

Comment: You need to loop until you get a point in the (0-50, 0-50) region.

Comment: That's better. Here's an alternative `while` condition:  `while not (0 <= x <= 50 and 0 <= y <= 50):`

Comment: Another little optimisation to make sure the while loop *definitely* finishes: Instead of recreating `theta` for each attempt, store it and increase it by a random amount `d` where `d < pi / 2` :)

Comment: Thanks @HumanCatfood that's a great idea! I think that d = pi/2 may do the job. Now it will converge in max 3 steps.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a point `(x, y)`

1. create another random point *anywhere* on the plane: `(x1, y2) = (random(), random())`
2. take the vector from your point to the new point: `(vx, vy) = (x1-x, y1-y)`
3. get the length `l` of the vector: `l = sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy)`
4. use `l` to normalise the vector (so it has a length of 1): `(vx, vy) = (vx / l, vy / l)`
5. make the vector 10 steps long: `(vx, vy) = (vx * 10, vy * 10)`
6. add it to your original point to get to the desired point: `(x1, y2) = (x + vx, y + vy)`

voilá :)

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import random
from math import sqrt

# Deviation
dev = 50

# Required distance between points
l = 10

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # First random point
    x0, y0 = dev*random(), dev*random()

    # Second point
    x1 = dev*random()
    y1 = y0 + sqrt(l**2 - (x1 - x0)**2)

    # Output
    print "First point (%s, %s)" % (x0, y0)
    print "Second point (%s, %s)" % (x1, y1)
    print "Distance: %s" % (sqrt((x1 - x0)**2 + (y1 - y0)**2))
```

Comment: In your case, if "x1-x0" is greater than distance "l", you will try to calculate the sqrt of a negative number, and the result will be a imaginary number.

Answer (score 0):

So, you got the formula `d=d1+d2=|x-x0|+|y-y0| , for d=10`

Let's examine what's going on with this formula:

- Let's say we generate a random point P at (0,0)
- Let's say we generate `y=random.randint(0,50)` and let's imagine the value is 50.

What does this mean?

`d1=|x-p[0]|=50` and your original formula is `d=d1+d2=|x-x0|+|y-y0|`, so
that means `d2=|y-y0|=10-50` and `d2=|y-y0|=-40`. Is this possible? Absolutely not! An absolute value |y-y0| will always be positive, that's why your formula won't work for certain random points, you need to make sure (d-d1)>0, otherwise your equation won't have solution.

---

If you wanted to consider Euclidean distance you just need to generate random points in a circle where your original point will be the center, something like this will do:

```
import random
import math


def random_point(p, r=10):
    theta = 2 * math.pi * random.random()
    return (p[0] + r * math.cos(theta), p[1] + r * math.sin(theta))
```

If you draw a few random points you'll see more and more how the circle shape is created, let's try with N=10, N=50, N=1000:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, it seems you need the generated circle to be constrained at certain area region. One possible choice (not the most optimal though) would be generating random points till they meet those constraints, something like this would do:

```
def random_constrained_point(p, r=10, x_limit=50, y_limit=50):
    i = 0
    MAX_ITERATIONS = 100

    while True:
        x0, y0 = random_point(p, r)

        if (0 <= x0 <= x_limit and 0 <= y0 <= y_limit):
            return (x0, y0)

        if i == MAX_ITERATIONS:
            return p

        i += 1
```

Once you got this, it's interesting to check what shape is created when you increase more and more the circle radius (10,20,50):

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, your generated random constrained points will form a well_defined subarc.

Comment: I don't the Euclidean distance. I mean the the absolute value of the difference in x-axis + the absolute vlue of the difference in y-axis =10 steps on lattice

Comment: @James I've edited my answer, I've explained you what's wrong with your original code, good luck

Answer (score 0):

`abs(x)+abs(y)=10` defines a [square](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+abs(x)%2Babs(y)+%3D+10), so all you need to do is pick a random value along the perimeter of the square (40 units long), and map that random distance back to your x,y coordinate pair.

Something like (untested):

```
x = random.randint(-10,9)
y = 10 - abs(x)
if (random.randint(0,1) == 0):
    x = -x
    y = -y
x = x + y0[0]
y = y + y0[1]
x0=(x,y)
```

Clipping the `x` range that way ensures that all points are picked uniformly.  Otherwise you can end up with (-10,0) and (10,0) having twice the chance of being picked compared to any other coordinate.